# to check int or not and continue to transaction in python

Tags: python

I am new in Python, and trying to code an account app, there is a value "balance", and the balance must be an integer, I added "try except blocks" but  if the client inserts an float or string, how can it start over again to ask for balance.

By the way, is there any efficient way than "try except" ?

````
  def __init__(self):
    self.balance = 0;
    self.savings = 0;
    self.savingsPercentage = 0;
    self.name = "The Dad";

theDad = Account();
print("Balance: ", theDad.balance)
print("Savings: ", theDad.savings);

addMoney = input("Add some amount: ");

while True:
  try:
    addM = int(addMoney);
    break
  except ValueError:
    print("Invalid...Please insert an integer...")
    addM = addMoney;
    break
if type(addM) == int: 
  theDad.balance = theDad.balance+addM;
  print("Last Balance: ", theDad.balance);
  theDad.savingsPercentage = int(input("What percent do you want to save? : "))
  savingBalanceAmount = (addM*theDad.savingsPercentage)/100;
  theDad.savings = theDad.savings+savingBalanceAmount;
  print("Balance Amount to Saving: ", savingBalanceAmount, "added on Savings..")
  theDad.balance = theDad.balance-savingBalanceAmount;
  print("Balance: ", theDad.balance);
  print("Savings: ", theDad.savings);
  print("........................");
  print("New Transaction.....");
  addMoney = input("Add some money: ");

  while True:
    try:
      addM = int(addMoney);
      break
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid...Please insert an integer...")
      addM = addMoney;
      break
  if type(addM) == int:
    savingBalanceAmount = (addMoney*theDad.savingsPercentage)/100;
    theDad.savings = theDad.savings+savingBalanceAmount;
    theDad.balance = theDad.balance+(addMoney-savingBalanceAmount);      print("Balance Amount to Saving: ", savingBalanceAmount, "added on Savings..")
    print("New Savings Total is: ", theDad.savings, "Last Balance Total is: ", theDad.balance)
    print("Thank you..")
  else:
    print("Try again...")
else:
  print("Try again...")```

Thank you..
````

Comment: check for `x == int(x)`

Comment: Move the `addMoney = input(...)` line to inside the `try`. Remove the `break` from the `except` block.

Comment: @karakfa no. That is not equivalent.

Comment: What is wrong with `try-except`, what is "inefficient" about it?

Comment: `addM = addMoney` should be `addMoney = input("...")`, and the `break` should be dropped from the handler. Catching an exception is relatively expensive, but since the plan is to wait for more user input, it's a cost you can ignore.

Comment: In python, unlike some other languages (*cough* Java) a try-except block is not a bad choice for a control structure in some cases. Python has a "better to ask forgiveness than permission" attitude, so it's normal to catch an error rather than set up an `if` statement to prevent the error from happening.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has to input an integer, then you shouldn't exit the while loop until that is true.

```
addMoney = input("Add some amount: ");

while True:
    addMoney = input("Add some amount: ");

    try:
        addM = int(addMoney);
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid...Please insert an integer...")

# No need to check if addM is an int; the previous loop guarantees it.
theDad.balance = theDad.balance+addM;
print("Last Balance: ", theDad.balance);
theDad.savingsPercentage = int(input("What percent do you want to save? : "))
```

If there is no exception, a `try` block has virtually no cost. If there *is* an exception, catching it is relatively time-consuming, but no where near the amount of time you can expect the following call to `input` to wait for more user input, so you can ignore that cost.